# Why does adding a subshell in zsh change the output of combined pipe and here string commands?

Tags: zsh

I am currently working with Bash and came across a peculiar behavior involving pipes (`|`), subshells (`( )`), and here strings (`<<<`). Specifically, I found that the presence or absence of a subshell results in different output for what I thought were similar commands.

Consider the following two commands:

1. `echo "bbb" | (cat <<<aaa)`
2. `echo "bbb" | cat <<<aaa`

The first command, which involves a subshell, produces this output:

```
aaa
```

The second command, without a subshell, produces this:

```
bbb
aaa
```

I expected both commands to output the same result because in both instances, I am piping the output of `echo "bbb"` to `cat` and also providing `cat` with the string `aaa` via a here string. However, it seems that the inclusion of a subshell in the first command changes the behavior.

Could someone please explain why these two commands yield different results and what role the subshell is playing in this?

---

Update:

I apologize for a mistake in my initial question. The shell I was actually using was zsh 5.9 (MacOS), not Bash.

In zsh 5.9, the outputs of the two commands are the same as I described originally.

I have also tested with bash 3.2.57, and found that both commands result in aaa.

This raises a new question: Why do zsh and bash behave differently for what appear to be identical commands? I would appreciate any insights.

Comment: Can't reproduce with bash 5.2, what version do you have?

Comment: `ksh Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01` in WSL2 only produces `aaa`  for either command. I would think it is because `cat` can only read from one stdin and my guess is that the `<<<` is tied to `cat` so the input from `|` is ignored. Not an expert on this (-;. Good luck!

Comment: @washingweb are you able to stably reproduce this?

Comment: Thirding, I get just `aaa` twice, using Bash 5.1.

Comment: Hi everyone, I sincerely apologize for the confusion caused by my original question. I incorrectly stated that I was using Bash, but I was actually working with zsh 5.9. I've updated the question to reflect this. Thank you all for your contributions and for your understanding. I appreciate your patience as I correct this mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal shells (i.e. most shells other than zsh), a program's standard input can only come from one source, and its standard output can only go to one target. In these commands, you're giving two conflicting sources for input to the `cat` command: the pipe from `echo`, and the here-string `<<<aaa`. What happens when you do this is that the shell sets stdin to one of them, and then replaces that with the other. It just happens that the pipe gets assigned first, so the here-string replaces it and the here-string is what `cat` actually gets.

zsh, on the other hand, has a [feature called multios](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) (presumably short for "multiple I/Os"), which lets you redirect input from multiple sources, and zsh itself will read from each of the sources in sequence, and pipe the combined result to the command as its stdin. It's a bit like piping from `cat source1 source2 source3 ...`.

So in the case of `echo "bbb" | cat <<<aaa`, zsh reads from the pipe ("bbb"), then from the here-string ("aaa"), and pipes the combined result to `cat`.

But it only does this multios trick when both redirects are supplied as part of the same command. So in the case of  `echo "bbb" | (cat <<<aaa)`, the subshell creates a different command context, and the inputs don't get combined. It pipes "bbb" to the stdin of the subshell, but then in the subshell it replaces that with the here-string "aaa". The same happens even if you just use a command group, like `echo "bbb" | { cat <<<aaa; }`.

BTW, multios also works with output redirects, although here it replicates the entire output stream to all of the targets (rather like `tee`). And again, it only does this if all of the redirects are part of the same command. So:

```
echo "aaa" >file | cat       # sends "aaa" to the file *and* terminal
(echo "aaa" >file) | cat     # only sends "aaa" to the file
{ echo "aaa" >file ;} | cat  # only sends "aaa" to the file
```

See [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673145/zsh-understanding-sequence-of-redirections-and-pipe-with-pointers) for a more extreme example.